# В чем разница синхронизации?

Tags: java, android

Вот есть класс в котором блокируется мютекс `notes`

```
public static class Note
{

    public final List<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addNote(int index, String note)
    {
        System.out.println("Сейчас будет добавлена заметка [" + note + "] На позицию " + index);
        synchronized (notes)
        {
            notes.add(index, note);
        }
        System.out.println("Уже добавлена заметка [" + note + "]");
    }

    public void removeNote(int index)
    {
        System.out.println("Сейчас будет удалена заметка с позиции " + index);
        String note;
        synchronized (notes)
        {
            note = notes.remove(index);
        } System.out.println("Уже удалена заметка [" + note + "] с позиции " + index);
    }
}
```

Чем это будет отличаться от такого кода в котором заблокирован мютекс `this`

```
public static class Note
{

    public final List<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addNote(int index, String note)
    {
        System.out.println("Сейчас будет добавлена заметка [" + note + "] На позицию " + index);
        synchronized (this)
        {
            notes.add(index, note);
        }
        System.out.println("Уже добавлена заметка [" + note + "]");
    }

    public void removeNote(int index)
    {
        System.out.println("Сейчас будет удалена заметка с позиции " + index);
        String note;
        synchronized (this)
        {
            note = notes.remove(index);
        } System.out.println("Уже удалена заметка [" + note + "] с позиции " + index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`synhronized(this)` - определяет в качестве лока экземпляр класса.

`synhronized(notes)` - поле этого экземпляра.

В данном контексте разницы не будет между `this` и `final` полем объекта. Т.к. в обоих случаях объект синхронизации однозначно связан с интансом класса.

Comment: ну хорошо допустим в этом случае `synhronized(this)` определяется в качестве лока обьект мютекс этого класса, но ведь все равно `synhronized` то конкретно указывает на метод... Какая разница какой обьект указывать в качестве мютекс? Можете привести пример по которому будет видна разница? Вот если так то будет так, а если вот так то по другому...

Comment: самый простой пример, это сделать в вашем коде поле static. Тогда потоки независимо от оттого к какому объекту будут обращаться, будут блокироваться и поочередно получать доступ. Сейчас же, потоки блокируются на объекте класса.

Comment: Странно, но я  все равно не пойму... при чем тут поле статик? 'Сейчас же, потоки блокируются на объекте класса.' - всмысле и в первом и втором случае? так а как сделать, чтоб в этом же виде этих методов, но была разница? При чем тут статик?

Comment: Попробуй этот код запусти в разных потоках static class A {
        static final Object lock = new Object();

        public void method() throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (lock) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: А потом убери статик и еще раз попробуй

Comment: static обеспечаивает что объект будет один и тот же для всех объектов из за этого и доступ для всех объктов будет синхронизировать им. Без статик у нас синхронизация привязывается только к интансу класса.

Answer (score 1):

Ни чем, и советую даже больше использовать ReentrantReadWriteLock для таких процедур с блоком try, если это многопоточное приложение. Пример:

```
public void addNote(int index, String note)
{
    writeLock.lock();
    try {
        notes.add(index, note);
    }
    finally {
        writeLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: вот интересно, а чем synchronized отличается от  reetrantreadwritelock ? и  почему второй более предпочтительнее?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov разница в том что synchronized работает всегда в одном потоке в данный момент времени исполнения, ReetrantReadWriteLock в Вашем же случаи будет работать с несколькими потоками сразу. При наличии конкуренции, потоки, которым повезло с CAS избегут переключения контекста и сразу пойдут на выполнение, другим же придется парковаться

Comment: у блока synchronized есть несколько режимов, и в зависимости от того в каком он находится, потоки будут себя по разному вести. в режиме thin они тоже крутятся на CAS'ах

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov допустим, но! - он всегда работает одинаково: сначала пытается сделать CAS, пользуясь стандартными средствами jvm, и если ему это удается, то захватывает lock и выполняется дальше, если же CAS - break, то вызов идет в ОС и поток паркуется (дизейблиться для скедулинга OС). Т.е. получаем, что в отличие от synchronized при не concurrent thread, ReentrantReedWriteLock будет всегда делать CAS, чтобы зайти в критическую секцию и не важно заходит ли туда один thread или много

Comment: Но, как это не удивительно cas'ы не всегда хорошо,  иногда лучше просто использовать обычную синхронизацию. любопытная статейка http://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/ . сам недавно с этим сталкивался, rwl в некоторых случаях жутко медленный

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov могу увидеть бенч тесты?

Comment: в статье той исходники есть, ну и вот мои наброски https://gist.github.com/izebit/6fe28d0a278409311bad1c07bfa2489e

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov благодарю, пересмотрю на досуге

Answer (score 1):

Разница в том, что поле `notes` можно сделать `private`, и тогда только класс будет определять, какой код будет исполняться в критических секциях, связанных с данным объектом. Во втором случае можно написать:

```
    Note notes = new Note();

    new Thread( () -> {
        synchronized ( notes ) { 
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep( 10 );
            } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    } ).start();

    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep( 50 );

    notes.addNote( 0, "whatever" );
```

и `addNotes` не завершится, пока не завершится поток.

Обычно стараются уменьшить доступность mutex извне, чтобы для понимания, кто его использует, нужно было читать меньше кода. Исключения бывают, например синхронизированные обертки над коллекциями (`Collections.synchronizedXXX`) используют в качестве mutex саму обертку, чтобы позволить синхронизацию при использовании итераторов и стримов.